# Xcode 8 Swift 3 IOS 10 Popup like InfoBubble

Tags: swift3, xcode8, ios10

I want to do a popup like this: (see images)

I like the way the popup will get the free space depend where you click

I like the pointer of the popup that show us where we click.

Is there anything like Pods or something exist that will help me to achieve that ?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using [corin8823/Popover](https://github.com/corin8823/Popover/) , its simple and easy to use but you should specify the direction of popover to open and also its height 
you can check [cuzv/Popover](https://github.com/cuzv/Popover) library too